# Event not being pushed to dataLayer in GTM (Wordpress site)

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, laravel-blade

I have a landing page with my dataLayer variable set up on a Wordpress site. I'm noticing in the Preview Mode that my events are **sometimes** not being recorded in the preview debugger. Could someone help me see what I could be doing wrong?

I'm sharing my .php template file and my GTM setup below. I'm using PHP blade templates (Laravel) if that helps. Clicking "Sign up" leads to some PHP code that makes an API call and then retrieves a response from a server. That is then saved into the variable $response.

```
<head>
   <script async src="mygoogletagmanager.comurl"></script>
   <script>window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [] </script>
</head>


**.blade.php file**
@if('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
    @if(isset($response))
        <script>
            window.dataLayer.push({
                'event': 'myEvent',
                'eventCallback': function() {
                     console.log('hello world!');
                     window.location="https://someotherurl.com"
                },
               'eventTimeout': 2000
            })
        </script>
     @endif
@endif

<form method="POST">
    <button>Sign up</button>
</form>
```

What I'm seeing in the preview mode is that the event is not being recorded, but the console.log is happening and the URL changes when I click the button.

Thanks in advance for your help